# Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell, but cell is "text"

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to store a numerical value (1, 2, or 3) in a variable after reading it from an excel table. I am using apache poi.

I don't think any code is necessary here, as it is a conceptual issue.

When I make the column of numbers into "number" format in the excel sheet and try to store it in an `int` or `double` it says "Cannot convert type String to type int"

When I make the column of numbers into "text" format in the excel sheet and try to store it in a `String` variable, it says "Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell"

How can I read and store these values in this conundrum?

Comment: Try getting the cell values along the lines of the example in [Getting the cell contents](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents). `DataFormatter.formatCellValue` will always return a `String` independent of the data type of the cell in `Excel`.

Answer (score 0):

If your range is not too big, you can loop through the entries:

```
Sub mac()

'put each cell value in range into an integer array
Dim rng As Range
Dim ints() As Integer
Set rng = Sheets(1).Range("A1:A4")

'doesn't work
'ints = rng.Value

'should work if there are no data problems
ReDim ints(1 To rng.Cells.Count)
For i = 1 To 4
     ints(i) = rng.Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i

End Sub
```

However, I suspect that you have an issue because at least one of your entries has a leading quote or some similar issue. For example, a cell entry of "1" will not get read in as the integer 1. You will need some extra code to handle your specific data problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont have a set size of the table. My cells simply have the value "1" "2" or "3" no quotes, or extra characters. When I make the column numerical format, that changes to "1.00" "2.00" or "3.00" as it should. Either way java doesnt like the format.